# Two Scheme code samples and their equivalent expression in Common Lisp

Tags: scheme

I am reading an article which uses Scheme for describing an implementation. I know a bit of Common Lisp but no Scheme.

I am hoping you will be so kind as to explain two Scheme code samples and show me how they correspond to Common Lisp.

First, what does this Scheme mean:

```
(define (content cell)
    (cell ’content))
```

I believe it means this: define a function named `content` which has one argument named `cell`. In Common Lisp it is written as:

```
(defun content (cell)
   (...))
```

Am I right so far?

I am uncertain what the function's body is doing. Is the argument (`cell`) actually a function and the body is invoking the function, passing it a symbol, which happens to be the name of the current function? Is this the corresponding Common Lisp:

```
(defun content (cell)
   (funcall cell ’content))
```

Here is the second Scheme code sample:

```
(define nothing #(*the-nothing*))
```

I believe it is creating a global variable and initializing it to `#(*the-number*))`. So the corresponding Common Lisp is:

```
(defvar nothing #(*the-nothing*))
```

Is that right? Does the pound symbol (`#`) have a special meaning? I'm guessing that `*the-nothing*` is referring to a global variable, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking: yes to both, with one major caveat. More specifically, the first one is accepting an argument called `cell` and calling it with the symbol 'content. (BTW, your unicode quotation mark is freaking me out a bit. Is that just a copy-paste issue?)

In the second case, the hash is a shortcut for defining a vector. So, for instance:

```
(vector? #(abc)) ;; evaluates to #t
```

However, the hash also has quoting behavior. Just as the first element of

```
'(a b c)
```

is the symbol `'a` (and not the value of the variable named `a`), the first value in the vector

```
#(*the-nothing*)
```

is the *symbol* `'*the-nothing*`, rather than the value of a global variable.

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry to freak you out with the quotation mark; yes, it's a copy-and-paste.